# Probability related to Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

It is required to obtain the $E[(X+1)!]$ where $X$ follows the Poisson distribution with the parameter $\lambda$.

**My approach**

The given Expectation can be written in the following form:

$E[(X+1)!]=E[(X+1)X]=E(X^2+X)=E(X^2)+E(X)$

Is my approach correct? I am not sure. I have done this as $x$ can take only non negative Values.

Comment: $(X+1)!=(X+1)X!$, which is different from what you have.

Comment: I have not written the $(x-1)(x-2)...2.1$ as $x$ can only take non negative values. Am I right?

Comment: Since we don't know exactly what $X$ is you can't do a general expression like this.